# How to cancel the exit option in c#

Tags: c#, console, exit

I need to know if there is an option to cancel the exit key in the console application?

I added an image url describing the button that i want to cancel, surrounded with red color.

http://i44.tinypic.com/2dj18d0.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of Alt+F4. Im sure 80% of SO users use that shortcut.

Comment: @MarsOne That question seems to refer to WinForms based on the answers.

Comment: Also it is important which os is used. I dont know if this works under Win 7 but at XP it worked fine if you import the system32.ddl and use ControlEventType.CtrlShutdownEvent

Comment: @MarsOne, on top of that, there are lots of other possible ways to shut down a running process (ie. Ctrl+C, or via TaskManager). But that is not what the OP is asking - he just wants to remove the X-button.

Comment: Hello, im using Win 7 and i just need to remove the X button.
The guides that you gave me dont work.
do you have other  guides?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a Windows API.

This code do the trick:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BlogConsole
{
    class API
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, uint uIDEnableItem, uint uEnable);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
        internal const UInt32 SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
        internal const UInt32 MF_ENABLED = 0x00000000;
        internal const UInt32 MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001;
        internal const UInt32 MF_DISABLED = 0x00000002;
        internal const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;

        public static void EnableCloseButton(IntPtr handle, bool bEnabled)
        {
            IntPtr hSystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(handle, false);
            EnableMenuItem(hSystemMenu, SC_CLOSE, (uint)(MF_ENABLED | (bEnabled ? MF_ENABLED : MF_GRAYED)));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the way you call it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
    API.EnableCloseButton(handle, false);
}
```